# Unsure what I am doing wrong, simple middle substring

Tags: java, string

Here's the link to what I'm doing, simple practice:
 http://codingbat.com/prob/p162477

However, its telling me that when it makes front = false,

```
        public String theEnd(String str, boolean front) {
            String stringPart;
            if (front = true) {
                stringPart = str.substring(0, 1);
            } else {
                stringPart = str.substring(str.length()-1,str.length());
            }

            return stringPart;
         }
```

returns it as it would when true anyway. I don't wanna learn bad habits :(

EX: Elephant returns E, when it should return t. I'll check back later, i need a LOONNNNG rest. Probably making stupid mistakes

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem:

```
if (front = true)
```

You meant:

```
if (front == true)
```

Currently it's *assigning* `front` a new value of `true`, then evaluating that result and finding it's true - so it will *always* take the first character.

There are three ways of fixing this. One is as above, and just be more careful. One is to use:

```
if (true == front)
```

which will prevent you from making the typo, because you can't assign *to* the constant `true`.

However, I'd prefer to get rid of the literal entirely:

```
if (front)
```

However, you can *also* make this whole method simpler with the conditional operator:

```
public String theEnd(String str, boolean front) {
    int start = front ? 0 : str.length() - 1;
    return str.substring(start, start + 1);
}
```

Comment: Graah!!! I feel like an idiot now :(
Ive learned the difference a thousand times and always make that mistake at least one time :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the equality with

```
if (front == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote (front = true) in your if statement. This does not compare front to true. This sets front equal to true.

I am shocked that your compiler did not yell at you for this statement. You should have gotten a warning. If you can, please make sure that you compile with all warning options turned on, then pay attention to each warning.